# How to access the global variable in Ajax sucess of kendo grid update?

Tags: ajax, angular, kendo-grid

Currently Developing web Application using AngularJS using with Kendo. When I save inline edit grid need to hide my save button and want to show back the Add button. For Show and Hide I use `*ngIf`. In this class I define `public isAddEdit: Boolean;` I cannot access the variable in success scope.

```
update: function (options) {
    $.ajax({
        url: HttpUrl.UpdateBlog,
        contentType: "application/JSON",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(options.data.models),
        success: function (result) {
            options.success(result);
            this.isAddEdit = false;
            $('#save').remove();
            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        },
    })
```

This is my view

```
<div id ="btndiv" class="col-sm-12">
     <button *ngIf="!isAddEdit" id="addblog" class="k-button grid-top-button-override k-primary add-button page-name" (click)="addStock()">{{'Addblog' | translate}}</button>
     <button *ngIf="isAddEdit" id ="save" class="k-button grid-top-button-override k-primary save-button page-name" (click)="clicksave()">{{'Save' | translate}}</button>         
</div>

<div class="row grid-override">
     <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the `this` is related to the AJAX callback function therefore you are not accesing the variable you want.
Try it with an arrow function:

```
       success:(result) => {
            options.success(result);
            this.isAddEdit = false;
            $('#save').remove();
            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
       },
```

Comment: I think it`s more appropriate to use ng-show, ng-hide in order to hide or show the button, because what ng-if does is remove the DOM element.     Also I think that there is no refresh of the view therefore it does not read the value of the variable. Try to debugg the variable somewhere in the view.

Comment: Did you wrap the `console.log(this.isAddEdit)` inside a `setTimeout(){}. `Because otherwise is going to be called before you have the response.

Comment: yes  the value changed. I read the value before I get the response. there is no refresh may cause the issue.

Comment: This is a very tiny example but maybe you are missing something: http://jsfiddle.net/yhabibyhabib/Lvc0u55v/9271/

Comment: Did my answer help you?